# Can't understand how to validate entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to interactively validate an entry widget in tkinter to only allow the user to enter characters in the alphabet. 
I have already read a very popular thread ([Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988)) and from that I have tried to figure out my solution but I just cannot seem to get it working. 
In the comments of that thread was a solution that only allowed numbers, I have used that for one area of my program and it works perfectly! Code here:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def testVal(inStr,i,acttyp):
    ind=int(i)
    if acttyp == '1': #insert
        if not inStr[ind].isdigit():
            return False
    return True

entry = Entry(root, validate="key")
entry['validatecommand'] = (entry.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I would like a solution like this, with the only change being that it accepts letters instead of numbers. Any help appreciated

Comment: Just replace `isdigit` with `isalpha`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's the solution you're looking for:**

```
def testVal(inStr,i,acttyp):
    ind=int(i)
    if acttyp == '1': #insert
        if not inStr[ind].isalpha():
            return False
    return True
```

**Heres some other things which might be useful:**

- `.isdigit()` tests if a string is an integer
- `.isalpha()` tests if a string contains only letters
- `.isalnum()` tests if a string contains only letters and numbers
- `.isupper()` tests for uppercase
- `.islower()` tests for lowercase

For other datatypes you can use `isinstance()`, for example `isinstance("34.5", float)` will return `True`

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: thank you it works great, I wasn't aware of isalpha() i tried ischar() earlier as I guessed that might work as it seemed logical.